# The method '[]' was called on null. problem ...Receiver: null ....Tried calling: [](0) .....flutter problem

Tags: mysql, android-studio, flutter, xampp

```
Widget _drawTopStories() {
  return Container(
    color: Colors.grey.shade50,
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, top: 10),
          child: _drawTitle("TOP STORIES"),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: Card(
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: postapi.fetchWhatNew(),
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapShot) {
                Post post1 = snapShot.data[0];
                Post post2 = snapShot.data[1];
                Post post3 = snapShot.data[2];
                return Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    _drawSingleRow(post1),
                    _drawDiver(),
                    _drawSingleRow(post2),
                    _drawDiver(),
                    _drawSingleRow(post3),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen of 2 reasons :

**First reason :**

Since Future Builder is asynchronous builder , You need to check the `ConnectionState` first before showing any widget.

```
if(snapshot.ConnectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) return CricularProgressIndicator();
```

**Second Reason** :

Maybe the actual snapshot is null , which means that you are not receiving any data from the `fetchWhatNew` . So you need to check first `if(snapshot.hasData)` which tells you if you are receiving data or null.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the snapshot.data unless you're sure it has data;

```
if (snapShot.hasData) {
  Post post1 = snapShot.data[0];
  Post post2 = snapShot.data[1];
  Post post3 = snapShot.data[2];
  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      _drawSingleRow(post1),
      _drawDiver(),
      _drawSingleRow(post2),
      _drawDiver(),
      _drawSingleRow(post3),
    ],
  );
}
return CircularProgressIndicator();
```